# Can I install ubuntu in ViewPad 97i?

Tags: installation, tablet, ubuntu-touch

ViewPad 97i is a pad device that can install win7 and have usb2.0 port.

Can I use it to install ubuntu?

I want to know if someone has tried this for ubuntu . I can not decide if I should buy it or ipad2.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start Ubuntu from USB stick as a live system. And when all things running fine - then simply try it :).

Comment: thanks . I want to know if someone has tried this for ubuntu . I can not decide if I should buy it or ipad2 .